# How can I integrate my fitbit data in my own Android app?

Tags: android, fitbit

I want to use my heart rate date and number of steps from fitbit account in my own android app. Do you know how can I do that? I find how to login with my fitbit account, but nothing helpful about how should I have this data in my app. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fitbit API: https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/

You will need to register your app with Fitbit (https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/new) and implement OAuth 2.0 to access user data. You can make HTTP request and load your user data after that.